# Python - stuck in a loop when trying to store an array of list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I am iterating through the dataframe and try to store the "total" list for each id.

The dataframe look like this:

```
id    total    difference
 1     29         3
 1     21         2
 2     39         0
 2     22         9
```

What I have tried so far:

```
total_list=[]
for i, row in df.iterrows(): 
    total_list.extend(df.total.loc[df.id==row.id].tolist())

print(total_list) # this never gets print
```

total_list should look like [[29, 21], [39,22]]

Comment: How ist the output supposed to look like?

Comment: You want `df.groupby('id').total.agg(list)`

Comment: @timgeb I added the expected output

Comment: That 31 should be a 21, right?

Comment: @RafaelC sure, I'm not very familiar with `pandas` dupes yet.

Comment: @timgeb thanks for the catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without looping, as long as I understand correctly. <del>I'm assuming that 31 in your output should be a 21.</del>

Setup

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,29,3],[1,21,2],[2,39,0],[2,22,9]], columns=['id', 'total','difference'])
>>>
>>> df
   id  total  difference
0   1     29           3
1   1     21           2
2   2     39           0
3   2     22           9
```

Solution

```
>>> df.groupby('id')['total'].apply(list).tolist()
[[29, 21], [39, 22]]
```